Using Slice in Polars Rolling with Group_by
I was trying to slice a weight Series based on the length of the rolling window. Use cases can be e.g. we want to apply some custom weights for rolling average. (I understand there's already a rolling_mean implemented.)
Could someone help explain why I have the error below and what is the proper way to achieve what I described above? Thanks!
Let's say my rolling window has a length of 5. The first 4 rows will have a length of 1, 2, 3, 4 and therefore I only want to get the first few weights. From the fifth row on, I expect the weights to be always [.1, .2, .3, .4, .5].
The following code 'kinda' works, but not really (as I expect [0.5], [0.4, 0.5], ..., [0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]. for the first 4 rows:
pl.DataFrame({
    't_idx': [1 ,2 ,3, 4, 5],
}).rolling('t_idx', period='5i').agg(
    -pl.col('t_idx').len().cast(pl.Int64).alias('start'),
    pl.col('t_idx').count().alias('end'),
    pl.lit(pl.Series([.1, .2, .3, .4, .5])).slice(-pl.col('t_idx').len().cast(pl.Int64), pl.col('t_idx').count()).alias('weights')
)

shape: (5, 4)
┌───────┬───────┬─────┬───────────────────┐
│ t_idx ┆ start ┆ end ┆ new               │
│ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ --- ┆ ---               │
│ i64   ┆ i64   ┆ u32 ┆ list[f64]         │
╞═══════╪═══════╪═════╪═══════════════════╡
│ 1     ┆ -1    ┆ 1   ┆ [0.1]             │
│ 2     ┆ -2    ┆ 2   ┆ [0.1, 0.2]        │
│ 3     ┆ -3    ┆ 3   ┆ [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]   │
│ 4     ┆ -4    ┆ 4   ┆ [0.1, 0.2, … 0.4] │
│ 5     ┆ -5    ┆ 5   ┆ [0.1, 0.2, … 0.5] │
└───────┴───────┴─────┴───────────────────┘

However, once I extend the number of rows to 6, I get some error which I don't fully understand.
pl.DataFrame({
    't_idx': [1 ,2 ,3, 4, 5, 6],
}).rolling('t_idx', period='5i').agg(
    -pl.col('t_idx').len().cast(pl.Int64).alias('start'),
    pl.col('t_idx').count().alias('end'),
    pl.lit(pl.Series([.1, .2, .3, .4, .5])).slice(-pl.col('t_idx').len().cast(pl.Int64), pl.col('t_idx').count()).alias('weights')
)

thread 'polars-4' panicked at crates/polars-core/src/frame/group_by/aggregations/agg_list.rs:109:58:
range end index 6 out of range for slice of length 5
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PanicException                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[828], line 3
      1 pl.DataFrame({
      2     't_idx': [1 ,2 ,3, 4, 5, 6],
----> 3 }).rolling('t_idx', period='5i').agg(
      4     -pl.col('t_idx').len().cast(pl.Int64).alias('start'),
      5     pl.col('t_idx').count().alias('end'),
      6     pl.lit(pl.Series([.1, .2, .3, .4, .5])).slice(-pl.col('t_idx').len().cast(pl.Int64), pl.col('t_idx').count()).alias('new')
      7 )

File ~/virtual_environments/vve_3_11_6/lib/python3.11/site-packages/polars/dataframe/group_by.py:896, in RollingGroupBy.agg(self, *aggs, **named_aggs)
    868 def agg(
    869     self,
    870     *aggs: IntoExpr | Iterable[IntoExpr],
    871     **named_aggs: IntoExpr,
    872 ) -> DataFrame:
    873     """
    874     Compute aggregations for each group of a group by operation.
    875 
   (...)
    884         The resulting columns will be renamed to the keyword used.
    885     """
    886     return (
    887         self.df.lazy()
    888         .rolling(
    889             index_column=self.time_column,
    890             period=self.period,
    891             offset=self.offset,
    892             closed=self.closed,
    893             group_by=self.group_by,
    894         )
    895         .agg(*aggs, **named_aggs)
--> 896         .collect(no_optimization=True)
    897     )

File ~/virtual_environments/vve_3_11_6/lib/python3.11/site-packages/polars/lazyframe/frame.py:1967, in LazyFrame.collect(self, type_coercion, predicate_pushdown, projection_pushdown, simplify_expression, slice_pushdown, comm_subplan_elim, comm_subexpr_elim, cluster_with_columns, no_optimization, streaming, background, _eager, **_kwargs)
   1964 # Only for testing purposes atm.
   1965 callback = _kwargs.get("post_opt_callback")
-> 1967 return wrap_df(ldf.collect(callback))

PanicException: range end index 6 out of range for slice of length 5

Tried doing slicing without rolling window and it was fine even when length=6 is greater than the length of the Series:
pl.select(
    pl.lit(pl.Series([.1, .2, .3, .4, .5])).slice(-5, 6)
)

shape: (5, 1)
┌─────┐
│     │
│ --- │
│ f64 │
╞═════╡
│ 0.1 │
│ 0.2 │
│ 0.3 │
│ 0.4 │
│ 0.5 │
└─────┘


A PanicException is often an indicator of a "bug" in the underlying Rust library. This might be worth raising on GitHub.

Minor: pl.len() is the same as pl.col(...).len() and counts the number of rows in a context. In contrast, pl.col(...).count() counts the number of non-null elements in the column.

As mentioned in the comments, the PanicException can be an indicator of an issue in the underlying Rust library and should be reported as an issue on polars' GitHub page.
Still, you can achieve the expected result, by creating a list[f64] column of weights before the aggregation. During the aggregation, weights is not created by only sliced.
pl.Config.set_fmt_table_cell_list_len(5)

(
    df
    .with_columns(
        pl.lit([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]).alias("weights")
    )
    .rolling("t_idx", period="5i")
    .agg(
        pl.col("weights").list.slice(0, pl.len()).first()
    )
)

shape: (6, 2)
┌───────┬───────────────────────────┐
│ t_idx ┆ weights                   │
│ ---   ┆ ---                       │
│ i64   ┆ list[f64]                 │
╞═══════╪═══════════════════════════╡
│ 1     ┆ [0.1]                     │
│ 2     ┆ [0.1, 0.2]                │
│ 3     ┆ [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]           │
│ 4     ┆ [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]      │
│ 5     ┆ [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5] │
│ 6     ┆ [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5] │
└───────┴───────────────────────────┘


Thanks @Hericks for your solution, although it seems a bit awkward to me that I had to define a list of weights for every row.
In fact, I didn't realize that there's another issue with the results from my code: I expected pl.Series([.1, .2, .3, .4, .5]).slice(-1, 1) to give me [0.5]. Instead, it's giving me [0.1] for t_idx = 1. Your solution would give me the correct result if I change your slice into `pl.col('weights').first().slice(-pl.len(), pl.len()).
I'll report this to polars' Github as you mentioned.

@jackaixin Yes, I've noticed this weird slicing behaviour as well and think this is a bug. I'd also think that using pl.lit([0.1, ..., 0.5]) directly in .agg(...) (avoiding the weights column) should give the same result, but it doesn't. Hopefully, some clarification will be provided in the issue. Thanks for raising!
